# onTouchEvent together with gestureDetector.onTouchEvent on android

Tags: android, drawing

I have an issue when using onSingleTapUp of GestureDetector and onTouchEvent of the View together. Both onSingleTapUp  and ACTION_DOWN/UP sections of the onTouchEvent manipulate same object set before drawing on the canvas.

I want to stop onTouchEvent continuing if it is clearly a single tap. I am not sure how to avoid this. Should I use synchronize instead?

```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                  //code here 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                  //code here    
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                  //code here 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

//try this:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
     super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

}
```

Comment: Its not working. When I had this code single tap didnt get hit. None of the other onTouchEvent actions get executed apart from (ACTION_DOWN).